# Slide only mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have problem with my mobile menu. I have two version menu in my page - normal and mobile. When I openn my page in normal size(PC) I see good menu. Whn I click zoom in google chrome I see mobile menu. If I click button menu to expend it menu then I see mobile menu. When I back in normal version page - then I`DONT SEE MENU, both normal and mobile. Why?

```
<nav>
<button class="toggle-menu"><img src="img/navicon.png""/></button>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka5</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I try this jQuery code, hovever this not work good:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-menu").click(function(){
        $("ul").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    if ($(window).width() < 801) {
        $( "ul" ).click(function() {
            $( this ).slideUp();
        });
    }
});
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is broken. Also, where is your CSS to make this responsive?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-menu").click(function(){
        $("ul").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    if ($(window).width() < 801) {
        $( "ul" ).click(function() {
            $( this ).slideUp();
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<button class="toggle-menu"><img src="img/navicon.png"></button>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Zakladka5</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: When I draw page I see mobile version. I click several times in menu. When I want collapse mobile menu and dismiss(zoom -) my menu in all versoin was hide. Why? The code CSS is not important in this problem. I have shared both selectors in normal and mobile version my page. Understand?

Comment: I want create drop-up menu only is mobile version.